# Разбиение массива и вывод по частям

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разбить массив `mysql_num_rows` на 20 элементов и вывести их? У меня есть код

```
if ($_GET["id_cat"] != "") {
    $cat_1  = str_replace(",", " OR categ_id=", $_GET['id_cat']);
    $zapros = " (categ_id=$cat_1)";
    if ($_GET["id_gor"] != "") {
        $zapros .= " and gorod=$_GET[id_gor]";
    }
    $ath = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM garant_object WHERE $zapros");

} else {
    if ($_GET["id_gor"] != "") {
        $zapros .= "WHERE gorod=$_GET[id_gor]";
    }

    $cat_1 = str_replace(",", " OR categ_id=", $_GET['id_cat']);
    $ath   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM garant_object $zapros ");

}
```

Как организовать разбиение массива по LIMIT 20 и ссылки для вывода данных на экран?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

при составления запроса используйте констуркцию LIMIT - она и отвечает за количество данных необходимых для выдачи с сервера а также указывает с какой позиции выдавать